# Add new route in Restful route and use this in form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I added a new route for a restful controller:

```php
Route::get('admin/store_productos', 'AdminController@store_productos');
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

And I use it in a form:

```php
{!!Form::open([
    'route' => 'admin.store_productos', 
    'method'=> 'POST',
    'files' => true])!!}
   <div class="row">
    {!!Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'input-field col s12', 'placeholder' => 'Inserte Nombre del articulo'])!!}
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    {!!Form::text('precio', null, ['class' => 'input-field col  s12', 'placeholder'=>'Inserte precio del articulo'])!!}
  </div>

  <div class="row"> 
    {!!Form::text('descripcion', null, ['class' => 'input-field col  s12', 'placeholder'=>'Inserte descripcion del articulo'])!!}
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    {!! Form::file('path') !!}
  </div>
  {!! Form::submit('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Route `[admin/store_productos]` not defined

I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because your additional route is not named:

```php
Route::get('admin/store_productos', 'AdminController@store_productos')
    ->name('admin.store_productos');
```

Comment: i try it but now I'm getting this error:  MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: That's because your form is set to do a `POST` request, but the route is defined as a `GET` one. You probably want to change the route definition to `Route::post(...)`.